# Dynamic Legends in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: legend, arcgis-pro, dynamic

I just tried to use Dynamic Legends in ArcGIS Pro 1.2 and have not been able to find them in either the application or its documentation.

I expected to find them as something like an `Only show classes that are visible in the current map extent` checkbox on an Items tab in the Legend properties, like there is in ArcMap.

A [GeoNet thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/116445) confirmed that they were absent from the first version (presumably 1.0).

Has anyone found them in ArcGIS Pro 1.2, or know when they are expected to be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic Legends were just added at 1.4!

[image: Only show features visible in the map extent]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Dynamic Legends are not there yet in ArcGIS Pro 1.2.